# Get multiple column from DataTable

Tags: c#, sql, datatable

I want to get two columns from DataTable like this

```
 //method to get data as DataTable from db
var dtTasks = db.GetTableBySQL($"exec Task @para = {Para}");

 var currentPendingTasks = (from DataRow dr in dtTasks.Rows select dr["TaskId"], dr["Name"]).ToString();
```

but for some reason in my second column I get

> The name 'dr' does not exist in the current context

Is not possible to select multiple columns foreach DataRow?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You could create an anonoymous collection with this syntax

```
var currentPendingTasks = (from DataRow dr in dt.Rows
                            select new 
                            { 
                                TaskId = dr["TaskId"], 
                                Name = dr["Name"]
                            });
```

But probably a simpler method to create a new DataTable containing only some columns from your original table is the following

```
var currentPendingTasks = dt.DefaultView.ToTable(false, "TaskId", "Name");
```

MSDN [DataView.ToTable method](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/wec2b2e6(v=vs.110).aspx)

Answer (score 0):

you can achive that yins List :

```
 var data= dtTasks.AsEnumerable().Select(x => new
 {
   TaskId = (int)x["TaskId"],
   TaskName= (string)x["Name"]
 }).ToList();
```

then :

```
var TaskId= data[0]. TaskId
```

Comment: I don't want to take them in one string, I want to get one object foreach row with that two columns.

Comment: Something equivalent to this:    `var parameters = assignNotificationTableType.Select(x => new { x.TaskId, x.Name }).ToList();` but with DataTable no List